# DHCP export using netsh

Tags: dhcp, netsh

I'm trying to export a DHCP database using the following command: `netsh dhcp server export c:\dhcpdb.dat all`

However it completes with the error

> WARNING: Could not obtain host information from machine: [server].
>   Some commands may not be available.

I've had a good look around but can't see this error appearing with the netsh command. I've held off importing to the new box. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you running this on the local server or a remote dhcp server?

Comment: Running the command locally on a 2003 R2 server.